# Entity Framework Core trying to cast custom type to other custom type (InvalidCastException)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've created a relatively complex structure of entities. I'm creating a quiz site and in this site I want to have multiple types of questions and therefor also custom types of answers.

I've created a simple method where an answer gets created based on the type of question it is answering. The object I'm getting is correct - it has the correct type and all fields are filled in correctly as well. Upon saving the context with a newly added answer of type `MultipleAnswersRepeating` I get an error that entity framework is trying to cast my object to another answer type, `MultipleAnswers`.

> Unable to cast object of type 
>    xxx.Models.Answers.MultipleAnswersRepeating' to type 'xxx.Models.Answers.MultipleAnswers'

See the class definitions:

```
    public class MultipleAnswers : Answer
    {
        [ForeignKey("AnswerId")]
        public virtual ICollection<Partials.PartialAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class MultipleAnswersRepeating : Answer
    {
        [ForeignKey("AnswerId")]
        public virtual ICollection<Partials.PartialAnswerRepeating> Answers { get; set; }
    }


    public class PartialAnswerRepeating : PartialAnswer
    {
    }

    public class PartialAnswer : PartialAnswerBase
    {
    }
```

Can it be that the problem is that the list in `MultipleAnswersRepeating` is of type `PartialAnswerRepeating` which inherits from `PartialAnswer` which is also the type of the list in `MultipleAnswers`? Might Entity Framework confusing the two because both can be seen as `MultipleAnswers` (but not as `MultipleAnswersRepeating`)?

I'm getting exactly the same error in a very small project with just the relevant classes. You can find this project [here](https://github.com/Wouter8/EFErrorTest).

I have specified all types that inherit from a base class in `OnModelCreating`.

```
        public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PartialAnswerBase> PartialAnswers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // Answers
            builder.Entity<MultipleAnswers>();
            builder.Entity<MultipleAnswersRepeating>();

            // PartialAnswers
            builder.Entity<PartialAnswer>();
            builder.Entity<PartialAnswerRepeating>();

        }
```

Comment: Could you show the DbContext with the DbSets?

Comment: See this project: https://github.com/Wouter8/EFErrorTest it contains everything to reproduce the error.

Comment: I can't create the database with your sample app. `The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'Answer' is not instantiable and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type`. It's kind of tricky figuring out what you want with these models. Why there's a base and partials?

Comment: @jpgrassi thanks for looking into it. Did you clone my project? I can run that project and get the error above.

Comment: Yep, I did clone it, but couldn't add a migration/update the db with your existing one, because of the abstract Answer class. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to achieve, I can help more. Your models seems a bit over-complicated at first sight, but I could be just missing something.